# How to sum specific column after filtering

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

its a simple table getting data from php

```
   <table style="margin-right: 200px;" id="myTable" class="table">
      <thead style="margin-right: 200px;">
        <tr style="font-size: 12px;">
          <th style="font-size: 12px;width: 3%;" class="lead">S.no</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Contract No.</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Commodities</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Seller</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Buyer</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">FCL</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Rate</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Weight</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Bill Amount</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Commision</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Shipment Period</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">ETD</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">ETA</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Mode Amount</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;display: none;" class="lead">Mode</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Status</th>
          <th style="font-size: 12px;" class="lead">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="font-size: 12px;margin-right: 200px;">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `indent`";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $sno = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $sno = $sno + 1;
          echo "<tr>
        <th scope='row'>" . $sno . "</th>
        <td>" . $row['contractNo'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['commodities'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['seller'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['buyer'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['fcl'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['rate'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['billAmount'] . "</td>
        <td id='loop' >" . $row['commision'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['shipmentPeriod'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['etd'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['eta'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['modeAmount'] . "</td>
        <td style='display:none;'>" . $row['mode'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['statusPayment'] . "</td>
        <td > <button style='font-size: 12px;' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#editModal' class='edit btn btn-sm btn-primary' id=" . $row['sno'] . ">Edit</button> <button style='font-size: 12px;' class='delete btn btn-sm btn-primary' id=d" . $row['sno'] . ">Delete</button>  </td>
      </tr>";
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <td id="total">0</td>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

i have found the answer on how to sum the column but while filtering it it does not add the values which are being filtered it just shows all the commision column summed the table is from datatables.net

and this is the function i am running to get the sum

```
 $(function() {

  var TotalValue = 0;

  $("tr #loop").each(function(index, value) {
    currentRow = parseFloat($(this).text());
    TotalValue += currentRow
  });

  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = TotalValue;

});
```

it gets all the comission column but i want that after filtered it shows the summed value i hope you can understand what i want

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: i am getting the td value from sql so using id makes it easier can you tell me how to sum after filtering\

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: i will use the class but can you tell me how to sum values after being filtered

Comment: What "filtering" are you talking about here, I don't see any.

Comment: i have used the table from datatables.net they give filtering using search so after using search the rows become less but the comission column still gives the sum of all the rows i hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: And you expect us to be able to _guess_ that? At least _tag_ the question appropriately then (I added `datatables` now.)

Comment: You'll need to go look into what events datatables provides, and find one that fires after the data got filtered. You need to add a handler function that re-calculates your total then. https://datatables.net/reference/event/

Comment: please send code pleaseeeeeee

Comment: If you're using [tag:datatables] then you'll need to *use* datatables to get the data - you can't then process `$("tr")` as data tables will *not render* rows that aren't currently to be shown (eg if they're on a different page or, in this case, filtered).  I suggest starting here: https://datatables.net/manual/api

Comment: i dont understand anything can  you please just send a column filtering code please based on my code it will be very very helpful

Answer (score -1):

just put your code into a function

```
function get_total(){
     var TotalValue = 0;

   $("tr #loop").each(function(index, value) {
     currentRow = parseFloat($(this).text());
    TotalValue += currentRow
  });

  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = TotalValue;
}
```

recall this function after filtered

Comment: can you tell me how can I recall this after using the search input given by datatable.net

Comment: OP is using datatables, which will not render filtered/paged data, so processing `tr`s will not give all the data; which is OPs problem.

Comment: Are You using data table or normal table

Comment: I am using datatable from datatable.net

Comment: and i can not target the search input which is given by datatables.net so i can not put the onchange or onblur function to it

Comment: *can not target the input* - you don't target the input, you use the [tag:datatables] API:  https://datatables.net/manual/events / https://datatables.net/reference/event/ / https://datatables.net/reference/event/search

Comment: i do not understand this and it would be easy if there were any way to directly target the search input it would be great